# Slack User removed event

Tags: bots, slack

I developing a slackbot and have implemented events

just like a applied event on member joining channel
https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel

I need an event when user is being removed from team

Comment: Could you solve this? I can only listen to the user_change event and see if deleted is true, but this event fires every user change

Answer (score 0):

This kind of event currently does not exist. Check [this list](https://api.slack.com/events) for an overview of all existing events.

Please contact the Slack team and suggest this event for a possible future implementation at feedback@slack.com.